# Program to use class method in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, class, oop, methods

```
class student:
    
    college = "tcet"
    
    def __init__(self,name,age,marks):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.marks = 90
    
    @staticmethod             #This is a  StaticMethod Decorator
    def info():
        return "This is data of students"
    
    @classmethod              #This is a  ClassMethod Decorator
    def college(cls):     
        return cls.college
        
        
s1 = student("shubham",19,100)
s2 = student("luffy",20,99.99)

print(student.college())

print(student.info())
```

Getting this error:

```
<bound method student.college of <class '__main__.student'>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods are just another form of attributes in Python, so by naming a method `college` when a class attribute `college` has already been defined, the method object will replace the class attribute `college` that was holding the string `"tcet"`.

You can correct this by simply naming the attribute differently:

```
class student:
    
    _college = "tcet"
    
    @classmethod
    def college(cls):     
        return cls._college
```